# CSS Pie - Cut down to just the bits I need

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners, css3pie

Does anyone know of any resource that lets you produce a CSSPie file that only has the code for the features I want to use?

e.g. just border radius, or just gradients etc

Kind of like how modernizer allows you to make a custom version

It's kinda bulky when you are not using all its functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any easy way. Maybe as on the CSS3PIE forums http://css3pie.com/forum/.

Remember that it's only going to be downloaded for IE8 and lower, so it's only a slow down for a increasingly shrinking percentage of users.

For gradients you can use the filter syntax, for rounded corners he's drawing them in VML, so that's a little more involved.

Answer (score 0):

msdn has documentation on how to create specific filters and your own htc files. idk about any gradient generators, plus i don't think ie supports radial gradients, but this css covers basic gradients:

for ie5.5-ie7

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ff00ff', endColorstr='#ffffff');

for ie8

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#ff00ff', endColorstr='#ffffff')";

and you can find rounded corners htc here: http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/